# POST request with body as Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, post

I am trying to give a POST request in swift and trying to send a dictionary. there is a php script running on the server side. I am getting status 200 but not getting what php script is suppose to return.The post request function written is

```
 func uploadcompletedata()
    {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://something.php")!)
        _ = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        let contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
        //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
        request.addValue(contentType as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let body = NSMutableData()


        let JSON = (try!(NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["species":Student.sharedObject().helprequested!,"genus":Student.sharedObject().helpoffered!,"family":Student.sharedObject().helprecieved!,"ord":Student.sharedObject().disastermag!,"location":Student.sharedObject().textEntered!,"latitude":Student.sharedObject().latitude,"longitude":Student.sharedObject().longtitude,"store":Student.sharedObject().locationofimage,"acc":Student.sharedObject().email!], options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)))


        body.appendData(JSON)

        request.HTTPBody = body

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(response)")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")
            Student.sharedObject().locationofimage = responseString!


            var err: NSError?
            // var json = (try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary



            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{


            });


        }

        task.resume()
}
```

The snippet of php script that I have

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['species']) || empty($_POST['genus']) || empty($_POST['family']) || 
    empty($_POST['ord']) || empty($_POST['location']) || empty($_POST['latitude']) || empty($_POST['longitude']) || 
    empty($_POST['store']) || empty($_POST['acc'])
    ) {


        // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please enter all the details";
}
else {
//this is what is getting printed 
}
```

According to what I get after debugging, I am not able to enter this if condition in PHP

Kindly help

Comment: You might want to check out Alamofire. It's quite a good framework for requests. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire